# Confirming correct distribution assumption

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose that the chance of making one typo on a page is $p_1$, two typos is $p_2$, and making none is $p_3$. what distribution has the random variable "sum of typos on $n$ pages"?

sine the number of typos is categorically distributed (3 outcomes), the sum of $n$ iid copied is multinomial, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite.  A multinomial distribution is a multivariate distribution when the number of categories is more than $2$.  So what it is going to count is the number of times each of the three categories occurs across $n$ pages.  For instance, you might observe an outcome where there are $12$ pages with one typo, $3$ pages with two typos, and $57$ pages with zero typos, out of a total of $n = 12 + 3 + 57 = 72$ pages, but the total number of typos is a function of this vector-valued outcome:  it is $$12(1) + 3(2) + 57(0) = 18.$$  The same thing applies to the case where there is only one page--the random variable for which typo category is categorical, but the number of typos is a function of that category.